# Java - accessing public members via reflection

Tags: java, reflection, illegalaccessexception

I've read a whole bunch of SO questions, and I can't seem to find the answer.

I have the following class:

```
public class DatabaseStrings {
    public static final String domain = 
        "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS domain (" +
            "_id INT UNSIGNED, " +
            "account VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT '', " +
            "domain TINYINT(1) DEFAULT 0, " +
            "domain_string VARCHAR(20) DEFAULT '', " +
            "user_id INT UNSIGNED DEFAULT 0" +
        ");";
}
```

And elsewhere, I'm trying to access these strings:

```
for(Field field : DatabaseStrings.class.getDeclaredFields()) {
    field.setAccessible(true); // I don't know if this is necessary, as the members are public

    System.out.println(field.getName());
    System.out.println(field.getType());
    String value = (String) field.get(null); // This line throws an IllegalAccessException inside Eclipse.
    // Do something with value
}
```

Why do I get an IllegalAccessException? I can see in LogCat the following lines, if I remove the field.get line:

```
System.out    |    domain
System.out    |    class java.lang.String
```

References:

[Pitfalls in getting member variable values in Java with reflection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2020202/pitfalls-in-getting-member-variable-values-in-java-with-reflection?rq=1)

[Reflection: Constant variables within a class loaded via reflection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8125086/reflection-constant-variables-within-a-class-loaded-via-reflection?lq=1)

[Accessing Java static final ivar value through reflection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/850148/accessing-java-static-final-ivar-value-through-reflection/850151#850151)

Comment: Are you running with a `SecurityManager`?

Comment: Do you have any other non-static field (public or private) in this class?

Comment: It works fine for me on Win7 Java7-32bit. Also `field.setAccessible(true);` is not necessary with public fields that you want to read.

Comment: 1. The exception is shown inside Eclipse Indigo (sorry, should have put that).

2. All fields are public static final.

Comment: Add the exception error to your post so we can see.

Comment: "Unhandled exception type IllegalAccessException"

I have added a try-catch with pre-setting String value = null; and it works, so I'll settle for that for now. Thanks for your time, boys and girls.

Comment: @Aeisor Usually reason of thrown exception is printed after its name. [[Edit]] your question and add whole stacktrace.

Answer (score 4):

Needed to wrap the .get() in a try-catch block

```
String value = null;

try {
    value = (String)field.get(null);
    // Do something with value
} catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
    // Handle exception
}
```

Comment: So, you didn't get an IllegalAccessException at all. You got a compilation error because you didn't catch or declare a checked exception. Next time, paste the complete and exact error message you get. And don't confuse compiling a program with running it.

Comment: I think I was just staring at it for too long. Eclipse was giving me an "Unhandled exception type IllegalAccessException" which I took as it throwing an exception. 

I'm new to Java, and new to Eclipse. It was an honest mistake and perhaps could have been explained better in the question.